# What's the best way to authorize a back-end sever to use the google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working on a an application where my back-end server will push and pull data over the google drive sdk.  So, the back-end will only ever need a authorization via a single admin user's set of credentials.

Is the best way to do the authorization for this use-case to do what's described here?
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

It looks like I would manually authorize my back-end's user once and store the refresh token for later offline access, thereby not needing manual/human interaction ever again.

But is that actually the best way for this use case?  Is there another authorization workflow that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method described at the link you sent is appropriate when you are authing several end users. I find it's overkill if you only ever need to auth a single user. Too much code and faffing around for something that will only be used once.

Check out [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical) which is a one-time procedure which gets you the same result, without writing any code.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked on it some, I think the best way for my application is this:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

You create a Service Account through the admin console.  There's no messing around with a manual authorization step that could later break the app.

Comment: If you're looking for an account that is dedicated to the app (ie. no UI of its own), and not a general use account, then you're right - Service Accounts for the win. Just don't fall into the trap of thinking that a Service Account is somehow the same as your Google account. It's completely separate.